# Foreach array e criar um nome para array com mesmo ID

Tags: php, laravel-5

Bom a ideia e criar grupos de arrays com nomes exemplo,

```
$arrays = 
array(
       array( 'teamID' => '1151', 'username' => 'iLilithZ'),
       array( 'teamID' => '1111', 'username' => 'iLilithZ'),
       array( 'teamID' => '1151', 'username' => 'iLilithZ'),
       array( 'teamID' => '1111', 'username' => 'iLilithZ'),
       array( 'teamID' => '0', '   username' => 'iLilithZ'),
     );
```

fazendo um foreach dessas array, assim as array com teamID igual mostrem um echo no foreach de grupo 1, os outros id iguais grupo 2, etc.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você quer ordenar o array pelo id do grupo?

Comment: não, exemplo, eu leio um json e retorno ele em array, dai eu faço um foreach dele, quando ele faz parte de um grupo o teamID tem o id do grupo, podendo ter mais de 1 grupo no mesmo foreach, assim sendo, eu queria que tipo, se o id 25 não existe, diga que é grupo 1 dai outro id 25, seja parte do grupo 1 também, o exemplo de uso é igual o desse site, http://paladins.guru/match/pc/232442401

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arrays as $key => $row) {
    $result[$row['teamID']][] = $row['username'];
}
```

O resultado vai ficar assim:

```
array(
    1151 => array(
        "iLilithZ",
        "iLilithZ",
    ),
    1111 => array(
        "iLilithZ",
        "iLilithZ",
    ),
    0 => array(
        "iLilithZ"
    )
)
```

Depois você percorre esse novo array organizado imprimindo da seguinte forma:

```
$count = 1;
foreach ($result as $group) {
    echo 'Grupo '.$count++.PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($group as $player) {
        echo $player.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```